# Upload one app to the app market, but how can it accommodate the different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have built my react native to work for iPhone6. That is, the 'flex' values are geared for this phone. I want to upload this app to the app market, but there are so many different phones (iPhoneX, iPhone8 etc...). How do i release this app to the app market and cater for all these different screen sizes?

I know the different 'flex' values i need for each of the other phones, but how does the app market know which version with the right 'flex' is needed? I can't upload multiple versions of the app with different 'flex' values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to upload multiple apps for different screen sizes. One app will work across all the devices. Test your screens in all of the simulators in XCode and most probably the designs are going to fit all the screens. If not you can use libraries like `react-native-responsive-screen` to make sure that help making your screens responsive